# Microsoft Edge devtools application tab is empty

Tags: microsoft-edge

When I inspect the page and go to the applications tab it shows blank. This problem happens to me on all pages not just localhost.
[image]

I already repaired the installation and also installed the latest version but it's still the same.

Comment: Does it happen in Chrome at all? Do you have any DevTools extensions installed?

Comment: It doesn't happen in Chrome and I don't have anything else installed

Comment: Which version of edge and OS are you using？
You could try to go upper right corner of devtools and find out Settings> Preferences> slide to the bottom click "Restore defaults and refresh" refresh your devtools to see if issue persists.

Comment: Hello, Edge Version 120.0.2210.22, Windows 11 23H2 and restore settings not working

Comment: I think it is a bug.

Comment: I'm getting the same here. Edge Version 120.0.2210.22. Completely blank Applications tab. Doesn't happen in Chrome.

Comment: I have the same problem and the same version. This version is as beta version, correct?

Comment: Versión 120.0.2210.22 (Compilación oficial) stable aplicación, beta canal (64 bits)